# Fingertip drawing applications on Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm a new user to this interesting forum!

I want start developing an application for android and before starting i want learn about some android features...

The first android feature is how to correlate finger motion on the screen with java...

Are there any source code examples that show how to draw with your finger on an android screen?

Can you suggest a good place for me to download an example?

thanks

Answer (score 20):

The [ApiDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) that come with the SDK have an example called [TouchPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html) that does exactly this... it's a simple little finger drawing app. The source is actually very easy to read and it shows all of the basics.

Comment: No worries... I would have forgotten about it too if I hadn't been playing with ApiDemos last night.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be in version 17

Comment: I can see this example in Samples but when I try to import , it says "No Projects are found to import". where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this tutorial on drawing with a canvas](http://almondmendoza.com/2009/06/08/drawing-with-canvas-in-android/) in Android. There are some source code examples there for you as well.

Also, the [Android developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and tutorials on the Google site are great. That's what I started with.

Comment: guys links no longer exist now